# syntax serna free 4.4.0 docbookv4.5 won't publish pdf with fop

Tags: xml, xslt, apache-fop, docbook

I am using Syntax Serna free 4.4.0-20111114 docbookv4.5 and its publishing html in seconds
but when I try to publish in pdf with Fop
It freezes claiming to be 'running...'and 'publishing...' like forever - hours and hours

---

I have FOP configured and running; working fine on the command-line with the example(xml file - XSLT stylesheet) from the [apache site](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/quickstartguide.html).

Using an -xml file created with Syntext Serna Free with its xsl files from the software

XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!-- This document was created with Syntext Serna Free. -->
<!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML V4.5//EN" "docbookV4.5/docbookx.dtd" []>
<article>
  <title>Cybazah</title>
  <section>
    <title>CBZ</title>
    <para>To start the  System, you must click on the bookmark saved on the web browser e.g. Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox.  You will then see a page requesting login information. You must then enter your credentials to proceed.</para>
    <para>If you have forgotten your password, kindly contact the lab-in-charge for help</para>
  </section>
</article>
```

Command - Line

```
C:\Users\strath\fop-1.1>fop -xml C:\Users\strath\Desktop\xml.xml -xsl C:\Program Files\Syntext\Serna Free 4.4\xml\stylesheets\docbook-xsl-1.68.1\fo\docbook.xsl pdf.pdf
```

I get the following feedback

```
Mar 20, 2014 9:57:52 AM org.apache.fop.cli.Main startFOP
SEVERE: Exception
org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException: Don't know what to do with Free
        at org.apache.fop.cli.CommandLineOptions.parseUnknownOption(CommandLineOptions.java:731)
        at org.apache.fop.cli.CommandLineOptions.parseOptions(CommandLineOptions.java:403)
        at org.apache.fop.cli.CommandLineOptions.parse(CommandLineOptions.java:167)
        at org.apache.fop.cli.Main.startFOP(Main.java:161)
        at org.apache.fop.cli.Main.main(Main.java:208)
```

### How do I sort this out?

Am running it on windows 7

Comment: Converting any xml to html is much different than converting to FO and then to PDF via FOP. Although both processes use XSLT, they are very different. Your error is most likely caused by the FOP processor. You will need to either provide the FOP output (log) snippet or an FO file that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Try quoting your paths in your command line; especially the path to the XSLT. That's the path mentioned in the error (it sees "Free" as a separate arg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the paths now quoted (Thanks Daniel) the pdf file  was created but the  hyphenation patterns were irregular.
To sort this out I replaced the contents of:

> C:\Program Files\Syntext\Serna Free
>   4.4\xml\stylesheets\docbook-xsl-1.68.1\

with:

> docbook-xsl-1.78.1

from sourceforge with out changing the original foldername

Also there is need for a folder ***docbookV4.5*** in the directory of the xml file being published, with contents from [docbook-xml-4.5](http://www.docbook.org/xml/4.5/)

This is working from the command-line, and not the serna interface though.